# How to create homeomorphic spaces using Cartesian products?

Tags: general-topology

I found the following exercise in a textbook (Allen Sieradski):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Then there exists a topological space $Z$ such that $X \times Z \cong Y \times Z$.

There are exercises preceding this which illustrate the concept: Show that $(0,1) \times [0,1) \cong [0,1] \times [0,1)$ even though $[0,1] \ncong (0,1)$. That makes perfect sense to me. I am struggling with the generality of the statement - obviously I am unaware of some high-level content here.

To get an understanding of what's going on, I started playing with $X = \{0,1\}$ and $Y=\{0,1,2\}$ with the discrete topology, but I find it hard to discern a pattern that I could generalize. I already struck out with finding a $Z$ for $X$ and $Y$ the open and closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$, respectively. I don't even know whether this is going to be a pure existence proof or a constructive one ("This is how you make $Z$ from $X$ and $Y$: $\ldots$").

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can define $Z=X^\mathbb N×Y^\mathbb N$. Then

$X×Z=X×(X^\mathbb N×Y^\mathbb N) \cong (X×X^\mathbb N)×Y^\mathbb N \cong X^\mathbb N ×Y^\mathbb N =Z$

And

$Y×Z=Y×(X^\mathbb N×Y^\mathbb N) \cong  Y×(Y^\mathbb N×X^\mathbb N)\cong (Y×Y^\mathbb N)×X^\mathbb N \cong Y^\mathbb N ×X^\mathbb N \cong X^\mathbb N ×Y^\mathbb N  =Z$

Comment: Ah, of course...

Comment: Infinities really coming in clutch huh...

Comment: Yup, probably wouldn't have thought of that anytime soon based on the preceding examples in the exercise. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose the spaces $X, Y, Z$ are nice enough so that dimension behaves nicely. We would have $\dim(X) + \dim(Y) = \dim(X × Z) = \dim(Y × Z) = \dim(Y) + \dim(Z)$. Imagine, say $X = ℝ^2$, $Y = ℝ^3$. What does it tell us about $\dim(Z)$?